# Passportjs Local strategy never get called

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I am learning passportjs and i have the following code in my server.js,the problem i am facing is that the `passport.use('local',new LocalStrategy({})` in the below code is never called,the rest is working fine except for the localstrategy,been strugling with this for hours!!

I am learning passportjs and i have the following code in my server.js,the problem i am facing is that the `passport.use('local',new LocalStrategy({})` in the below code is never called,the rest is working fine except for the localstrategy,been strugling with this for hours!!

```
const express=require("express");
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const ejs=require("ejs");
const cookieParser=require('cookie-parser');
const passport=require('passport');
const LocalStrategy=require('passport-local').Strategy;
const session=require("express-session");
const app=express();
app.set(express.static,'public');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({secret:'library'}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.post('/auth/signUp',(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log('body',req.body)
    passport.authenticate('local',(err,user,info)=>{
        console.log("whattt",user)
        req.login(user,(err)=>{
            res.redirect('/auth/profile');
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});

app.get('/auth/profile',(req,res)=>{

    res.json(req.user);
});


app.get("/",async (req,res)=>{

    res.render('index.ejs');
});

passport.serializeUser((user,done)=>{
    done(null,user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done)=> {
    console.log("id",id);
    let data=[{id:1,name:"malouda"},{id:2,name:"Jason"}];
    let user = data.find((obj)=>{ return obj.id === id; });
    done(null,user);
});

passport.use('local',new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password'
},(username,password,done)=>{
    user={id:1,name:"malouda"};
    console.log("LocalStrategy")
    done(null,user);
})); 
app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("Listening on port 6000");
});
```

and in my index.js i have the following form

```
<form name="signUpForm" action="/auth/signUp" method="post" multipart='urlencoded'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password " id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Passport LocalStrategy is used for login authentication.

In Signup, you don't need the passport. In Signup, you just create the user by storing it in the database.

You need to add

```
Passport.authenticate(`local`, (err, user, info) => {}
```

In your **login** API to authenticate the user.

As the name suggests, **Passport.authenticate** authenticates the user credentials. SO first you need to create the user.

[Read more here.](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local)

Hope I cleared your thoughts.